# Challenges in Implementing the Blahut–Arimoto Algorithm for channel capacity computation

Tags: calculus, algorithms, information-theory, mutual-information

I've read the [Blahut–Arimoto Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blahut%E2%80%93Arimoto_algorithm) from the [original paper by Blahut](https://doi.org/10.1109%2FTIT.1972.1054855) and [Raymond Yeung's book](http://iest2.ie.cuhk.edu.hk/%7Ewhyeung/post/draft2.pdf), along with other sources. However, I'm having trouble understanding the computation of channel capacity in the algorithm, particularly in Fig.1 of Blahut's paper (corresponding to Theorem 1). Specifically, when $P_{j|k}^* = 0$, how can we calculate $P_j^* = \frac{exp(\sum_k Q_{k|j}log(P_{j|k}^*))}{\sum_j exp(\sum_k Q_{k|j}log(P_{j|k}^*))}$?

The first expression for $P_{j|k}^*$ assumes it is non-zero, derived with the assumption and a well-known IT inequality. The second is derived using KKT conditions. In some implementations (e.g., [here](https://www.rpgroup.caltech.edu/chann_cap/notebooks/blahut_algorithm_channel_capacity)), they assume $0 \cdot \log(0) = 0$, but I believe this is incorrect.

Consider the testing scenario with $Q=P\{Y|X\}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 0.5 & 0.5\\ 0&1 
\end{bmatrix}$. The capacity of this channel should be 1.5, with the achieved distribution being [1/3 1/3 1/3]. However, the algorithm does not yield these values.

Any insights or corrections would be appreciated.